# How to search cell value in a table

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

The searching object could be in any row and in any column so lookup alone wont do it.

Also I need it to return value of cell on right of it but formula that would return its position would be great

[Google sheet with the problem](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I-fONuBnozaaz3p95D1L6TyiYBWg7y-hk8pVjaGHE4Y/edit?usp=drivesdkhttps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In K5, enter formula :

```
=INDEX(A1:I22,SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:A22)*(A1:I22=K4)),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN(A1:I1)*(A1:I22=K4))+1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `OFFSET()` function with `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=OFFSET(A1,SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:G20)*(A1:G20=$I$4))-1,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN(A1:G20)*(A1:G20=$I$4)))
```

Comment: Though `OFFSET` is volatile and therefor slow on big datasets

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(K4; {FLATTEN(B5:G20)\{QUERY(FLATTEN(B5:G20); "offset 1"; 0); ""}}; 2; 0)
```

[image: 0]